When I try to perform a JEST test using a parameter fetched from a database, it simply doesn't work
When I try to perform a JEST test using a parameter fetched from a database, it simply doesn't work... I tried an example without a database, and it doesn't work the same way.
See Code
// Example function that queries IDs from the database
async function fetchIDsFromDatabase() {
// Simulating an asynchronous database query
return [1, 2, 3]; // Example list of IDs returned by the database
}
// Test using Jest
describe('Test for IDs returned from the database', () => {
let ids;
// Before all tests, fetch IDs from the database
beforeAll(async () => {
  ids = await fetchIDsFromDatabase();
});

// Test to verify if the list of IDs is not empty
test('Checks if the list of IDs is not empty', () => {
  expect(ids).toBeTruthy();
});

// Iterate over each ID returned from the database using test.each
test.each(ids)('Testing ID %i', async (id) => {
  // Here you can perform test operations for each ID
  expect(id).toBeGreaterThan(0); // Simple assertion example
  // Add more assertions as needed
});

});
the return IS
Test for IDs returned from the database
√ Checks if the list of IDs is not empty (2 ms)
× Testing ID %i (1 ms)
● Test for IDs returned from the database › Testing ID %i
`.each` must be called with an Array or Tagged Template Literal.

Instead was called with: undefined

  20 |
  21 |     // Iterate over each ID returned from the database using test.each
> 22 |     test.each(ids)('Testing ID %i', async (id) => {
     |          ^
  23 |       // Here you can perform test operations for each ID
  24 |       expect(id).toBeGreaterThan(0); // Simple assertion example
  25 |       // Add more assertions as needed

  at each (__TEST__/api.test.js:22:10)
  at Object.describe (__TEST__/api.test.js:8:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.508 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.

The problem is not with jest, the problem is with the code.
This is the correct code:
let ids = [];

beforeAll(async () => {
  ids = await fetchIDsFromDatabase();
});

test('Checks if the list of IDs is not empty', () => {
  expect(ids).toBeTruthy();
  expect(ids.length).toBeGreaterThan(0); // Ensure the array is not empty
});

describe('Dynamic ID tests', () => {
  ids.forEach(id => {
    test(`Testing ID ${id}`, async () => {
      expect(id).toBeGreaterThan(0); // Simple assertion example
      // Add more assertions as needed
    });
  });
});

Changes:

ids is properly initialized and scoped.
Asynchronous data fetching is handled correctly.
Tests verify that ids is not empty.
Dynamic tests are created after the data is available, avoiding issues with test.each trying to access ids before it is populated.

